# Writing on a XML file issue

Tags: java, xml

I have been trying to write something in a XML File, but nothing was written, don't know why.
Any help?

This is the code:

Here is the method I use to write on a XML File:

```
public static void writeXMLFile() throws ParserConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    /*<Drawer>
     * <Shape>
     *  <type></type>
     *  <color>
     *  <x1>
     *  <y1>
     *  <x2>
     *  <y2>
     * 
     */
    Element rootElement = xmlDoc.createElement("Drawing");
    Element mainElement= xmlDoc.createElement("Shape");
    mainElement.setAttribute("Color", "red");
    Text shapesTypeText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("Square");
    Element shapeType= xmlDoc.createElement("type");
    shapeType.appendChild(shapesTypeText);
    mainElement.appendChild(shapeType);
    rootElement.appendChild(mainElement);
    xmlDoc.adoptNode(rootElement);

    OutputFormat outFormat = new OutputFormat(xmlDoc);
    outFormat.setIndenting(true);

    File xmlFile = new File("saved.xml");

    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream (xmlFile);

    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outStream,outFormat);
    serializer.serialize(xmlDoc);
}
```

}

Comment: Mention your imports as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as follows;

```
            xmlDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDoc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("saved.xml"));

    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adoptNode, make it as appendChild

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        /*<Drawer>
         * <Shape>
         *  <type></type>
         *  <color>
         *  <x1>
         *  <y1>
         *  <x2>
         *  <y2>
         * 
         */
        Element rootElement = xmlDoc.createElement("Drawing");
        Element mainElement= xmlDoc.createElement("Shape");
        mainElement.setAttribute("Color", "red");
        Text shapesTypeText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("Square");
        Element shapeType= xmlDoc.createElement("type");
        shapeType.appendChild(shapesTypeText);
        mainElement.appendChild(shapeType);
        rootElement.appendChild(mainElement);
        **xmlDoc.appendChild(rootElement);**

        OutputFormat outFormat = new OutputFormat(xmlDoc);
        outFormat.setIndenting(true);

        File xmlFile = new File("saved.xml");

        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream (xmlFile);

        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outStream,outFormat);
        serializer.serialize(xmlDoc);
    }
```

**adoptNode**
This attempts to adopt a node from another document to this document.

**appendChild**
This adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.